# Populate select box with an array

Tags: jquery

I have a form containing two radio button, one select box and two arrays.
If I select first radio button then the select box values should be populated with `array1` and if radio button 2 is selected then select box should be populated with `array2`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var array1=["1","2","3"];
  var array2=["4","5","6"];
</script>

<form name="form" id="form">
  Radio button 1<input name="btn1" id="a1" type="radio" value="Radio button 1">
  Radio button 2<input name="btn1" id="a2" type="radio" value="Radio button 2" />

  <select id="s1" name="myname">
    <option selected></option>
  </select> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#a1').change(function() {
      alert('do array1'); 
    });

    $('#a2').change(function() {
      alert('do array2');
    });

  })           
</script>
```

I got the values of radio button, but how I'll populate select box with array values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### jquery

```
var array1=["1","2","3"];
var array2=["4","5","6"];

var map = { a1 : array1, a2 : array2 };

$('#a1, #a2').change(function() {
    $("#s1 option").remove();
    $.each(map[this.id], function(i, val) {
        var opt = $("<option />");
        opt.appendTo($("#s1")).text(val).val(val);
    });
});
```

#### html

```
Radio 1<input name="btn1" id="a1" type="radio" value="Radio button 1" />
Radio 2<input name="btn1" id="a2" type="radio" value="Radio button 2" />
<select id="s1" name="myname">
<option selected></option>
</select>
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ufC2k/1/)

Comment: +1 you beat me to...but I did make one additional suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name=btn1]').change(function(){
        var arr = [];
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'a1')
            arr = array1;
        else
            arr = array2;

        $('select#s1 option').remove();
        $.each(arr, function(index, item){
            $('select#s1').append('<option value="'+item+'">'+item+'</option>"');
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#radio_button").change(function(){
      $("option","#select_element").remove();
      var select_options = $("#select_element").attr("options");
      $.each(array,function()
      {
        select_options[select_options.length] = new Option(this[1],this[0],false,false);
      });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the values organized and more readable you could use the radio button value property like this...

```
<input name="btn1" id="a1" type="radio" value="1,2,3" />
<input name="btn1" id="a2" type="radio" value="4,5,6" />
```

And managing the change as such..

```
$("[name='btn1']").change(function (e) {
    var array = $(this).val().split(",");

    $("#s1").empty();

    $.each(array, function (index, value) {
       $("<option />").appendTo("#s1").text(value).val(value);
    });
});
```

This way you do not end up with variables "floating" around.